# Github commit gmail attachments using Google App Script

Tags: github, google-apps-script, gmail

Someone is sending files to my gmail account that I want to put in a Github repo. Any guides on how to write a Google Script to commit the attachments periodically?

If not possible, what other free alternatives do I have to automate this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should be possible, the difficulty will be in connecting to GitHub form google apps script but thankfully there is a JavaScript library for that.

You can create an apps script project that periodically (using a [time-based trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)) checks your Gmail inbox for new emails (filtering through a [search](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#searchquery), or you can [create a rule](https://www.lifewire.com/create-rules-in-gmail-4172416) with Gmail itself to use a custom label for the emails you want to upload to your GitHub repo).

Now, once you have the GmailMessage object, you can get the attachment(s) and to upload them to GitHub, you can use the [code from this script](https://script.google.com/d/1jI_BpCFqKstGFQ8sNY8nJwjOiXXhubKDvD7G9h6U1iE63mzX2e4U-ak_/edit?usp=sharing), I followed it to download data from GitHub before. I haven't tried committing yet so I would be curious to hear if it works for you.

Comment: Working without problems! Very easy to set up. I just had to change the base64Encode part to use the UTF-8 charset. Thank you!